# IntelliJ IDEA how to correctly pass $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION to npm-run-all

Tags: json, node.js, intellij-idea, npm

On my *Ubuntu 16.04* I use *IntelliJ IDEA ultima 2017.2* together with *node v6.11.2* and *npm v3.10.10* and 
want to debug a node.js application, which has the following *package.json* **start** entry:

```
"start:" "npm-run-all --parallel serve-static open-static"
```

According to the console output and [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197866/connection-refused-in-webstorm-npm-debug-configuration) I need to add **$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION** as first parameter (for node) to avoid the **Connection refused** error. 
Obvioulsy, I have tried

- to add $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION in the Run/Debug configuration as *Arguments*
- and as *Node options*

which resulted in calls like

```
node npm-cli.js run start-debug --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION
```

and

```
node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION npm-cli.js run start-debug --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
```

in each case $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION is not resolved and *node* treats it like a non-existing file.

I have also tried to add variable directly in *package.json* like

```
    "start:" "npm-run-all $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION --parallel serve-static open-static"
```

which also results in a **Cannot find module .../$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION** error.

So, how can I pass this option in order to debug that thingy in IntelliJ IDEA?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

adding `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` to `package.json` manually is the only way to debug the application started via npm script, because you have to make sure that Node.js is started with appropriate debug options (`--debug-brk`, `--inspect-brk`, etc), and the IDE can't control the way child processes are spawned - it can only pass options to the main process when starting it. But this option has to be passed to Node.js - not to **npm-cli.js**, **npm-run-all**, etc. If **npm-run-all** is an npm script that starts the app you'd like to debug with node.js, you need to modify this script accordingly, like:

```
"npm-run-all": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION myapp.js"
```

If your task runs a shell script, that, in turn, runs your app with node.js, you need to modify a shell script... The goal is to start the node process with debug options

Answer (score 0):

`$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` has to be argument for nodeJs, before executing nodeJs script.

```
"some:task": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./path/to/script.js"
```

All plugins / dependencies are nodeJs scripts. You just need to find correct path, and run that CLI with node, not as standalone CLI.

In your case `npm-run-all` (as most of CLI) is located under `node_modules/.bin/`:

```
"start:" "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./node_modules/.bin/npm-run-all --parallel serve-static open-static"
```