# IntelliJ NPM debug configuration not stopping on breakpoint?

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, webstorm

I am able to run my Express app from IntelliJ by creating a debug configuration.

[image]

However, when I place breakpoints and post a request to my app from Postman, the app does not stop at my breakpoints, although the application does execute and handle the request.

Do I need to do something special to debug my application?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your Npm script to make sure that Node.js is started with appropriate debug options (`--debug-brk`, `--inspect-brk`, etc) by passing `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` to it , as the IDE can't control the way child processes are spawned - it can only pass options to the main process when starting it.
If `dev` is the npm script that starts the app you'd like to debug with node.js, you need to modify this script accordingly, like:

```
"dev": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION bin/www"
```

These articles might be helpful: [IntelliJ IDEA how to correctly pass $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION to npm-run-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966125/intellij-idea-how-to-correctly-pass-node-debug-option-to-npm-run-all) and http://pavelpolyakov.com/2016/05/01/webstorm-npm-tasks-debug/.

Comment: thanks. this seems right, but i don't think i did it correctly. i modified the `scripts` tag in my package.json. previously i had `"dev": "nodemon --exec 'nf start'"`, which I changed to `"dev": "nodemon $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION --exec 'nf start'"`. I intended to add `--debug-brk` to the `node parameters` in the debug configuration, but when I run the configuration I get this output (see next comment), even though my configuration does not include any `node paramters` (the app behaves as it does previously if I revert my package.json changes)

Comment: `[nodemon] 1.18.9`
`[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter 'rs'`
`[nodemon] watching: src/**/*`
`[nodemon] starting nf start --inspect-brk=56003`

  `error: unknown option --inspect-brk`

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: i get a similar issue even if I hard code that flag. `"dev": "nodemon --inspect --exec 'nf start'"`, gives `error: unknown option '--inspect'`

Comment: it's strange, as `nodemon` does support these options. what nodemon version do you use?

Comment: as far as I can see, when starting nodemon like `nodemon --inspect --exec "node  src/main.js"`, the `--inspect` is actually appended to the command line, so that this option is passed to application being run, like `node  src/main.js --inspect`. This can explain the error

Comment: I think this syntax is correct, as my application runs without error, but IntelliJ still doesn't stop on my breakpoints: `"dev": "nodemon --exec 'nf start'"`, `"start": "node --inspect forever",`

Comment: try changing `"start"` to `"start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION forever"`. Not sure what is `nf` and `forever`, but, as i wrote, you need to make sure to pass `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` to node that starts your application

Comment: i'm not able to get `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` to pass, but i'm pretty sure this is correct because it seems to respect the debug port I specify (the app logs the debug port when it starts, and the port changes when I modify the command, however intellij simply does not stop on the breakpoints

Comment: "dev": "nodemon --exec 'nf start'",
    "start": "node --inspect=9229 forever",

Comment: when debugging NPM in WebStorm, you have to use `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION`, replacing it with `--inspect`, etc. won't work