# How to debug an npm application

Tags: intellij-idea, npm

I'm using run/debug configurations to run npm application:
[image]

and I run it in debug mode.

I don't know why but the application does not stop in breakpoints I put in the code.

The command I have in package.json is:

> "serve": "tsc && concurrently \"nodemon app.js\" "tsc --watch"

Answer (score 1):

For WebStorm versions <= 2018.3.x, you need adding `%NODE_DEBUG_OPTION%` variable to your script, like:

```
"tsc": "tsc && concurrently \"nodemon %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% src/main.js\" \"tsc --watch\""
```

These articles might be helpful: [IntelliJ IDEA how to correctly pass $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION to npm-run-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966125/intellij-idea-how-to-correctly-pass-node-debug-option-to-npm-run-all) and http://pavelpolyakov.com/2016/05/01/webstorm-npm-tasks-debug/.

Since 2019.1, it won't be required